# SQL trigger to insert values when the tables updated

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have written a trigger to execute when data is inserted on to a SQL Server table via a SSIS package. I want to insert today's date in to the date column in the table. My trigger is below it doesn't seem to work.

Can some one please help.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertDate]
ON dbo.Debtors
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Debtors
    SET InsertDate = GETDATE()
    FROM inserted
    WHERE Debtors.id = inserted.id
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a default value instead:

```
alter table dbo.Debtors add column InsertDate datetime default getdate();
```

No need for a trigger at all.